# Async/await On Property Changed

Tags: .net, asynchronous, async-await, viewmodel

I am looking for some best practices in async/await.
I have datepicker and observable collection,  i want to load data into observable collection on datetime changing asynchronously.
How can i modify my code to do that, nicely? I know, that properties can not be async. I know about commands, so maybe i need to bind async command on datepicker datetimechanged event?

```
public class LogViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public LogViewModel()
    {
        LogCollection = new ObservableCollection<Log>();
        DateTime = DateTime.Now.Date;
    }

    private DateTime _dateTime;

    public DateTime DateTime
    {
        get { return _dateTime; }
        set
        {
            if (_dateTime != value)
            {
                _dateTime = value;
                LogCollection.Clear();

                //long running code begins
                using (var ctx = new DataContext())
                {
                    ctx.Logs.Where(p => p.dt >= _dateTime && p.dt < _dateTime.AddDays(1))
                        .ToList().ForEach(z => LogCollection.Add(z));
                }
                RaisePropertyChanged("DateTime");
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Log> LogCollection { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that best practice is to keep VM and similar classes clear. So I prefer to subscribe to PropertyChanged event internally and move such logic to event handler (refactoring-friendly example):

```
public LogViewModel()
{
    if (!DesignerProperties.IsInDesignTool)
    {
        PropertyChanged += HandlePropertyChanged;
    }   
}       

private static string DateTimePropertyName = ExpressionHelper.NameOf((LogViewModel _) => _.DateTime);

private void HandlePropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == DateTimePropertyName)
    {
        //Start async operation in other thread via TPL Tasks/ThreadPool's QueueUserWorkItem etc. for example or using true-async IO operations (a bunch of real-async operations available in EF)
    }
}
```